# Read specific text from text files

Tags: powershell

I wrote a PowerShell script to compare two text files. In file1 the data is organised. But in file2 the data is not organised. I usually organize data manually. But now the data is increased. I need to automate organising using PowerShell.

PowerShell has to read data between two special characters. For example: `<****@` is my data. It has to read `****` only. this pattern repeats 'n' number of times.

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression `<(.*?)@` to match the relevant substring. `.*?` matches all characters between `<` and the next occurrence of `@` (non-greedy/shortest match). The parentheses put the match in a capturing group, so it can be referenced later.

```
Select-String -Path 'C:\path\to\file2.txt' -Pattern '<(.*?)@' -AllMatches |
  Select-Object -Expand Matches |
  ForEach-Object { $_.Groups[1].Value }
```

`$_.Groups[1]` refers to the first capturing group in a match.

Comment: Typo in the regex? `'<(.*?)q'`

Comment: @sodawillow Thanks for the heads-up. Fixed.